Power BI - Showing all Rows on a Filtered Visual
I am trying to build a visual to show payment progress for contracts but am having some difficulty having all the items show up in my visual when I use a slicer to filter the data. I am trying to be able to slice previous payments to have a historical view of payment progress.
In my data table not even line appears on every payment and it doesn't get recorded as a 0 either so when I filter to a payment the visual will only display the rows that have that associated payment number in my data table.
The pbix file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3wpe3w85fxvjsefhphs4p/Contract-Data.pbix?rlkey=6qbi25w0xge8wh6bl2i5wmvsk&st=clyp5prn&dl=0
I have tried to create a measure that ignores the filter, creating a measure to look at all rows and pull the last known value if it is not in the selected payment in the slicer, selecting the show values with no data, and creating a seperate table with all line guids.
Current Visual
My desired output
The raw data I am using:



Contract
Line Number
Line GUID
Pay Amount
Payment Number




1
1
AAA1
10
1


1
1
AAA1
500
2


1
1
AAA1
1000
5


1
2
BBB2
500
4


1
3
CCC3
500
2


1
3
CCC3
100
3


1
3
CCC3
100
7


1
4
DDD4
100
6


1
5
EEE5
500
3


2
1
111A
100
1


2
1
111A
500
3


2
2
222B
1000
3


2
2
222B
500
3


2
3
333C
500
2


2
3
333C
1000
3




I can't open the link, could you pls paste the data in your post?

Hi Ryan, I added the raw data in and updated the link to a dropbox one which might work better.

i can figure out the contact 1 and payment 4 is the fourth line of you sample data. May I know how to get Line 1 3, 4,5? why previous payment is 510?

The previous payment for line 1 in payment 4 should be 510 that's what was paid previously, 10 in payment 1 and 500 in payment 2. I was able to make a calculated column that figures that logic ok, but I still can only ever display the lines that are a part of payment number I have selected rather just making them show as a zero fr their current value if they aren't part of the selected payment.

still not clear about the logic. The expected output is that when you select contact 1 and payment 4, you want to get the table from line 1 to 5 and CO1. What is CO1? why previous for line 3 is 600? could you pls elaborate more about the logic of result?

Sorry, you can ignore line CO1, I was trying something and it's not needed. For Contract 1 and payment 4 line 3 would be 600 becuase 500 was paid in payment 2 and 100 was paid in payment 3. The logic I am trying to achieve is a running accumulating total for each line as the payment increases. I would like to have one column that shows the accumulated total for every previous payment for each line based on the selected payment in the slicer and one column that shows any amount being paid for the specific payment that I have actively selected in the slicer if there is one otherwise show a 0.

you can create two tables for selection
contract = DISTINCT('Table'[Contract])
paymentnumber = DISTINCT('Table'[Payment Number])

Do not create relationships between tables.
Then create mesaures
MEASURE =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Pay Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Contract] = MAX ( contract[Contract] )
            && 'Table'[Payment Number] = MAX ( paymentnumber[Payment Number] )
    )
) + 0

MEASURE 2=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Pay Amount] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Contract] = MAX ( 'contract'[Contract] )
            && 'Table'[Payment Number] < MAX ( paymentnumber[Payment Number] )
    )
) + 0


